# CodeIgniter : Included JS or CSS in view folder

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm include JS or CSS in Folder views codeigniter but experienced a

> 403 error,

How to solve it?

**example code** :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>views/data/index.js">
```

or

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . APPPATH; ?>views/data/index.css">
```

then came the error "

> NetworkError: 403 Forbidden

Kindly solution of masters.

Sorry if my english language is not good

Comment: You cant do it in view folder. You have to create a folder on your project root and need to place it their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest Answer to your problem is to create new directory in your application root like this:

```
-Your_Application
    -application
    -assets <-- Create this folder.
      -css  <-- Create this subfolder inside assets folder.
      -js   <-- Create this subfolder inside assets folder.
        -script.js <-- Place your script files inside js folder.
    -system
    -index.php
```

Now you are able to access your css and js files using url helper like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/script.js'); ?>" ></script>
```

Follow same procedure for css and make sure `url helper` is enabled from `config/autoload.php` like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**Want to know the reason behind this:**

The reason behind happening this is that your application outputs from `index.php` in your application root as CI implemented Front-controller design pattern.

So we don't need to place our public assets anywhere inside our application that's why CI restrict direct access to **application** and **system** folder from the public access.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you cannot have assets or supporting files on it. That wrong file structure of the codeigniter.
You can have a folder name **asssets** on a root and follow this steps.

you can add url path on **constraints.php** on **config folder** .... you define the url like this on constants :

NOte: xxx is your site name

```
define('ROUTE_STIE_PATH','localhost/xxx/'); 
define('ADMIN_CSS_DIR_FULL_PATH',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'assets/css/');
define('ADMIN_CSS_DIR_FULL_PATH',ROUTE_STIE_PATH.'assets/js/');
```

and then you can echo by simply on view or header

```
<link href="<?php echo ADMIN_CSS_DIR_FULL_PATH; ?>index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



<script src="<?php echo ADMIN_JS_DIR_FULL_PATH; ?>index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: But I want it in the folder view of her, do not want outside the application folder..

Comment: The codeigniter will not suitable for u then i guess ... Its MVC format and in the above answer it is cleary shown the reason why you cant keep assets jn view folder

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter comes with a .htaccess in the /application directory which contains

```
Deny from all
```

You'll need to remove this file or change it's ruleset to access js/css files etc from anywhere inside

```
application/*
```

It is however largely inadvisable to allow access entirely to the application.

Answer (score 0):

if its your requirement to have js or css file specific to view and you want to handle those file within view then:
Simplest way is, create file

```
xxxcss.php and xxxjs.php //put your js code or css style
```

Define Variable if required

```
$data['variable']="Something"; // This is optional if you need pass php variable to your js or css before loading in page.
```

load view in controller and pass to another view or directly load within view

```
$this->load->view('css.php or js.php',$data);
```